# Processing Json data with EXTJS

Tags: ajax, json, extjs

Java application sends to the front the following json data:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"","password":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"Administrator"}],"username":"admin"}]}
```

In the front I have an user model like the following:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Users', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   fields: [
      {name: 'id', type: 'auto'},
      {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
      {name: 'password', type: 'auto'},
      {name: 'roles', type: 'auto'},
      {name: 'username', type: 'auto'},
   ],
   autoLoad: true,
   proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '/web/user',
      reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'data'
      }
   }
});
```

Edit:
I updated the code and this way the data is loaded.

Also i made a grid so I can show the results.

```
Ext.define('App.view.Home', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.home',
  title: 'Home',
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [
      {
          xtype: 'gridpanel',
          store: 'Users',
          title: 'Users grid',
          columns: [
              {text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'id' },
              {text: 'Username', dataIndex: 'username', width : 200 },
              {text: 'Role', dataIndex: 'roles', width : 200 },
              {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', width : 200 },
          ]
      }
  ]
});
```

Now the question that remains is that the grid is showing `[object Object]` how could i be showing the part that i want from that object, as the `name` of the `role`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the reader type to JSON, This code is working for me:

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hjf)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('Users', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            fields: ['id', {
                name: 'username',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }],
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create("Users", {
            listeners: {
                load: function() {
                    console.log("Loaded " + this.getCount() + " records");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I also removed the mappings as I don't think that you need them.

**EDIT**

In regards to the data showing in a grid, the 'roles' property in the JSON data is an array, that's why it's showing in the grid as object, I've updated the fiddle to show a possible way to get this information, But it's not the recommended method. You should probably look at [associations](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Association) in ExtJs for this.

Reviewing the guide on the [Data Package](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/data_package.html) may also help with this.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('Users', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            fields: [{
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int' 
            }, {
                name: 'username',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'roles',
                type: 'auto'
            }],

            autoLoad: true,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, records) {
                    console.log("Loaded " + this.getCount() + " records");
                }
            }
        });

        var users = Ext.create("Users");

        Ext.define('App.view.Home', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.home',
            title: 'Home',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                store: users,
                title: 'Users grid',
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Id',
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                }, {
                    text: 'Username',
                    dataIndex: 'username',
                    width: 200
                }, {
                    text: 'Role',
                    dataIndex: 'roles',
                    width: 200,
                    renderer: function(v, metadata) {
                        return v[0].name;
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    width: 200
                }]
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('App.view.Home', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: sakir thanks for that, updated. @LogofaT I've updated the answer

Comment: My project uses extj 4.XX and this doesnt seem to work on that version

Comment: I have updated the fiddle so that it is compatible with ExtJs 4.1. The main changes are changing rootProperty to root and defining the roles field on the store.